# Find angle between three points, ([x,y], [x,y], [x,y]) allow for obtuse results. (Math and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, angle

I have the following function, to find the angle between 3 points.

(Where a point is defined as an array containing the x position as its first element and the y position as its second element, and the angle to measure is the angle created when a line is drawn through all three points.)

```
findAngle: function(a, b, c) {
    var ab = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b[0] - a[0], 2) + Math.pow(b[1] - a[1], 2));
    var bc = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b[0] - c[0], 2) + Math.pow(b[1] - c[1], 2));
    var ac = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(c[0] - a[0], 2) + Math.pow(c[1] - a[1], 2));
    var o1 = (bc * bc + ab * ab - ac * ac) / (2 * bc * ab);
    var o2 = Math.acos(o1);
    var o3 = o2 * (180 / Math.PI);
    return o3;
}
```

However, this only ever returns angles between 0 and 180 degrees. How can I have it return values between 0 - 180 degrees, *and* values between 180 and 360 when the angle is in fact obtuse?

Comment: You may get more relevant help at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: An angle of 180 degrees is a straight line. Obtuse angles are 90-180, and acute 0-90. This equation finds the smallest angle between two lines, which will always be somewhere between 0 and 180. If you wanted an angle larger than 180, you could subtract the angle from 360 (i. e. 360 - 90 = 270). It all depends on what reference point you want to use.

Comment: What criteria are you using for deciding between less than 180 degrees or greater than?

Answer (score 1):

Use atan2 function that has two arguments and returns result in range `-Pi..Pi` (add `2*Pi` to negative angles if needed)

```
angle = Math.atan2(crossproduct(c-b,b-a), dotproduct(c-b,b-a))
where
crossproduct(c-b,b-a) = (c.x-b.x)*(b.y-a.y) - (c.y-b.y)*(b.x-a.x)
dotproduct(c-b,b-a) = (c.x-b.x)*(b.x-a.x) + (c.y-b.y)*(b.y-a.y)
```

Comment: Note that depending on the orientation of the angle you are interested in, you might need to switch `a` and `c` in this formula or else you'll get your values negated.